# What happened to firebug? Is there a good replacement?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

I have been doing a lot of ajax development with JavaScript and found a lot of value in the console in firebug in Chrome telling me the post and response for a call. I can't seem to get firebug on anything any more and while I know Chrome's developer tools and firefox both have a console you can view, I only get things like a 500 error on an ajax call rather than a clear error that could point me in the direction of if there is a problem with a parameter, service address, etc.

Any recommendations on what tool to use?

Comment: I might be confused by what you're asking. You can get request/response bodies and headers in Chrome's Network tab. That said, have you ever tried Postman? It is an excellent tool for this kind of work.

Comment: I think I just found what I was looking for in the Chrome Developer tools. Specifically, the message under a preview of a request. I will check out Postman also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do almost everything and many more with Chrome Developer Tools
If you go to the Network tab in Google Developer Tools, you can see everything goes through the web browser. If you want to filter REST API calls, select **XHR** tab.
There you can see all the details. If it's Post Request then see the JSON body etc.

[image: Javascript Request]

In the preview tab, you can see the response you got for the API call.

[image: JSON response]

There are many ways to make Developer life easy using Chrome Developer Tools,
Use below references to know more.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

https://www.youtube.com/user/ChromeDevelopers/featured

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug was discontinued last year (2017).](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/)

> So it’s sad that Firebug is now reaching end-of-life in the Firefox
>   browser, with the release of Firefox Quantum (version 57) next month.
>   The good news is that all the capabilities of Firebug are now present
>   in current Firefox Developer Tools.

So, the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (which are built into Firefox) are recommended for debugging websites as the replacement for Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I use an older version of Pale Moon which still supports it. I know the replacements can do more but I mostly I use it for css and html. The replacements don't load as easily and don't always reflect css changes properly.